# Does "text" mean "to write"?

Tags: meaning

> I often text or blog about experiences I have with these products.

In the example above, it seems that "text" is used as "to write an article". But according to various dictionaries, the verb "text" just means to write a SMS message. Does "text" also mean "to write an article"?

Comment: No, it means to send a text message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **text** is to send someone a message by using a phone.

Comment: I'd add that the phrase which "to text" developed from is "to send a text message". It became "send a text", and then just "to text".